# framework not found GoogleMapsBase

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, google-maps

I'm getting this error

```
ld: framework not found GoogleMapsBase
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when running my build on Xcode after installing GoogleMaps on my Swift iOS application.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The GoogleMaps folder contains 3 frameworks instead of 1.
You'd need to include all 3 instead of just `GoogleMaps`

So in this case it would be

```
GoogleMaps
GoogleMapsBase
GooglePlaces
```